# Count items in postgreSQL table where specific condition is met

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multiple sql tables in my postgresql database and  my goal is to count how many item_id is per contract.This is my table of `contract_items`
[image]

So the result for WHERE contract_id=1, should be like this:

```
id contract_id include_from, item_id, label, num items
------------------------------------------------------
1     1     2021-02-26...       5     null     1
---------------------------------------------------
2     1     2021-02-26...       6     null     2
---------------------------------------------------
3     1     2021-02-26...       7     null    1
```

I tried like this, but in the end I have duplicate row for item_id 6

```
SELECT
    contract_items.*
    , COALESCE(t.numitems, 0)
FROM
    contracted_items
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                item_id
                , COUNT(*) AS numitems
            FROM
                contract_items
            WHERE
                contract_id = 1
            GROUP BY
                item_id
        ) t
        ON t.item_id = contract_items.item_id
WHERE
    contract_id = 1;
```

would anyone help me to correct my query, and to count item_id per contract?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this what you want? :

```
SELECT
    contract_id
    , item_id
    , MAX(include_from) lastincluded
    , MAX(label)        lastLabel
    , COUNT(*)          numOfItems
FROM
    contract_items
GROUP BY
    contract_id
    , item_id;
```

in that case you can do something like this :

```
select *
from (
     select * 
     , row_number() over (partition by contract_id, item_id order by include_from) rn
     , count(*) over (partition by contract_id, item_id) count
     FROM contract_items
) tb
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks.. is it possible to specify all fields from table contract_items with * not to write them manually... something like this `SELECT
    *,
    contract_id
    , item_id
    , COUNT(*)          numOfItems
FROM
    contract_items
GROUP BY
    contract_id
    , item_id;`

I have like 15 more fields in this table...

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to have the rows with first occurrence of item_id for a contract_id along with the count of that item_id against that contract_id you may use cte:

```
WITH CTE AS(
select id,contract_id,include_from,item_id,label,row_number()over(partition by contract_id,item_id order by id)rn,
count(*)over(partition by contract_id,item_id order by id) num_items
from contract_items)
SELECT id,contract_id,include_from,item_id,label,num_items FROM CTE WHERE RN=1
```